# Trivial hash for a consecutive sequence of input that doesn't have visible cycles in output

Tags: python, hash

In a simple tile-based image, if each area of grass has the same grass tile repeated on each square, it looks like a horrible moire pattern, but if three or four grass tiles are alternated, it looks surprisingly natural.

The preferable way to produce this is that each tile is chosen via a simple hash of its coordinates. (An alternative possible implementation is that they are chosen randomly at the start of the game, but I prefer the hash function if possible.)

The necessary properties for the hash function are:

- As fast as possible (ideally something like x+y mod N), with no cryptographic properties wanted
- No visible periods on the output: eg. x+y mod N fails because it always repeats the same N tiles across each row

Is there a simple arithmetic hash which would work, and be simpler than "seed(coords); return randomrange(N)", but if the input is "(0,0)","(1,0)","(2,0)"... the output doesn't have visible patterns in?

Would it be better to generate some random data at the beginning of the game to use?

Comment: Can't you generate random data as you're generating the tiles? So your "hash" would be `randint`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like

```
hash(coords) % number_of_tiles
```

Python's built-in `hash()` function does not really behave pseudo-randomly, but for this purpose, it's probably good enough.

Here's an example with 7 tiles:

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...     for y in range(10):
...         print ".oO^v<>"[hash((x, y)) % 7],
...     print
... 
O < o v . ^ > O > O
. v o < < O > ^ v o
< o > O . ^ o v O <
^ . O > o < . v > ^
o v . ^ ^ > O < v .
> ^ . v o < O > O >
. ^ o v < o > O v .
< O v o . v > ^ O >
v . ^ > O < o v . ^
O > ^ . . v o < < O
```

Comment: Doh! Sorry, I forgot to say, thanks for the clean approach, but that was one of the things I tried, and there was an obvious mod-2 cycle in the output -- I inferred it was doing a simple + or xor or similar. If you think that was just bad luck, I could try again.

Comment: @JackV.: Try with a different number of tiles – I added an example.

Comment: Hm. You're right, it looks ok if I restrict (or pad) the number of tiles to 7 (or probably another prime), even though the output is completely periodic for 2 and 4 tiles. I can't decide if I like that answer or not.